# Listening key events on system level

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I need to write an application, which will listen to some key events and after they occurs, application will do something (this isn't important for this question).

The application will run like a deamon - on background (possible on system  tray) and waiting for input.

The question is, how can I listen to key events on system level? I prefer some Unix C solution (priority isn't portability to non-Unix system), but if there is some handy Qt class, why don't use it?

EDIT: Isn't there some way, to tell the operating system something like: "Hi! I am here, wake me up on 'some keyboard event'!"?

Comment: Sounds like you have malicious intent. Building a keyloger to hijack someone's passwords?

Comment: Nope - I will add detailed description to my question. My goal is to create drop-down window, which will appear on some key event - which will user set. The application itself will from obvious reasons run on background and therefore I need to know, when some certain event occurs. That's why solution using root access doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

`qxtglobalshortcut` is for shortcuts. `Qt` offers different ways to handle native events. It is for example `QWidget::nativeEvent` or `QAbstractNativeEventFilter`.

But if you want to use system API, then you can try my code. It is code which executes inside separate thread and asynchronously invoke method to notify user when event occurs. Ready for copy-paste, but set name of your keyboard.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <QSystemTrayIcon>
#include <thread>

QSystemTrayIcon *tray;

void handler (int sig)
{
  qDebug ("nexiting...(%d)n", sig);
  exit (0);
}

void perror_exit (char *error)
{
  perror (error);
  handler (9);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);


    tray = new QSystemTrayIcon;
    QPixmap px(20,20);
    px.fill(Qt::green);

    tray->setIcon(QIcon(px));
    tray->show();
    tray->showMessage("hello","hello",QSystemTrayIcon::Information,1000);

    //need this to use invokeMthod
    qRegisterMetaType<QSystemTrayIcon::MessageIcon>("QSystemTrayIcon::MessageIcon");
    std::thread thread([tray]()
    {
        struct input_event ev[64];
        int fd, rd, value, size = sizeof (struct input_event);
        char name[256] = "Unknown";
        char *device = NULL;


        if ((getuid ()) != 0)
          qDebug ("You are not root! This may not work...n");


        //my keyboard,set name of yours
        device = "/dev/input/by-id/usb-SIGMACHIP_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd";

        //Open Device
        if ((fd = open (device, O_RDONLY)) == -1)
          qDebug ("%s is not a vaild device.n", device);

        //Print Device Name
        ioctl (fd, EVIOCGNAME (sizeof (name)), name);
        qDebug ("Reading From : %s (%s)n", device, name);

        while (1){
            if ((rd = read (fd, ev, size * 64)) < size)
                perror_exit ("read()");

            value = ev[0].value;

            if (value != ' ' && ev[1].value == 1 && ev[1].type == 1){ // Only read the key press event
             qDebug ("Code[%d]n", (ev[1].code));
             QMetaObject::invokeMethod(tray,"showMessage",Qt::QueuedConnection,Q_ARG(QString,"Was pressed"),Q_ARG(QString,QString::number(ev[1].code)),
                     Q_ARG(QSystemTrayIcon::MessageIcon,QSystemTrayIcon::Information),Q_ARG(int,500));
            }
        }
    });

    qDebug("after thread");
    return a.exec();
}
```

I used code from [here](http://www.thelinuxdaily.com/2010/05/grab-raw-keyboard-input-from-event-device-node-devinputevent/), but just changed it to be in `Qt` manner.

To run programm you must use sudo.

```
sudo /path/to/exe
#if you want to run it inside qt creator but with sudo
sudo /path/to/qtcreator
```

Comment: This solution is cool, but my application will lack root access. Thank you very much for solution using /dev/input, I knew, my goal could be somehow achieved this way.

Answer (score 1):

It's not Qt (yet) but is somehow connected, there is this class in the Qxt library called qxtglobalshortcut

Here is the link: http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/tip/qxtglobalshortcut.html

Comment: This looks promising, but do you know about some system library function? I would prefer it :)

Comment: I can't download it anywhere, is this project still active?

Comment: I believe Qt does not have anything like this. I see the project does not look very active but here I have found a link with an howto for Qt5 so I think it's worth a try: http://wiki.qt.io/LibQxt_in_QtCreator

Comment: Now I finnaly found, that library is no longer maintained - that explains my issues ...

Answer (score 0):

Short: You can't do this.
Longer answer: You can, but you have to write an keyboard-driver.

Even with root/Administrator privileges, you need an input-widget which will have OS input focus. (This is to avoid grabbing the input from other input widgets, like password-fields or your chat). - I fully agree ddriver's comment.

If your service has a focused-widget, you can use Widget's text-events or use [QObject::installEventFilter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter)

Another point: You can reuse/notify the event within your service but not send to other applications. See [notify](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#notify). If the service handled the keyboard event, no other application will receive the event. And if focus-widget's application already accepted key-event, your service does not get it.

But I do agree: Some OS allow to access the keyboad-devices. (Like Chernobyl's answer). For these, you can implement an own-Keyboard-device driver / handler. Example for Linux embedded is: [QWSServer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html).

Note for users: Using such driver is not save! Please be carefull if you use 3rd party keyboard-driver! For Windows it is highly recomanded only to use Windows-trusted drivers.

Anyway: Implementing an own keyboard-driver can solve Rainbow Tom's issue.

Comment: Keyboard driver? Sounds like a proper challenge. Thanks for awesome opinion. Now for real, if my application is running in background (or in system tray), how can I have focused widget?

Comment: You can't do this. (Like I said). Anyway and example for systray is here: [systray](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtjambi-4.5.2_01/com/trolltech/qt/qtjambi-systemtrayexample.html)

Comment: An example for systray is in your Qt under examples/widgets/desktop/systray. - Only in my mind: in the iconActivated-slot, show and focus a QLineEdit. Then you are in 'input-mode' and can handle the keypress. Hide the LineEdit to give keyboard back to OS.